# Angular compile

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angularjs-directive

I have to inset a directive dynamically from a controller
the directive should be like this

```
<synergy-chart series="s" options="o"/>
```

where s and o are js objects

I was thinking about from inside the controller I could do like this 
if the directive didn't require parameters this method works but since parameters are needed

```
var directive = $('<synergy-chart series="'+series+'" options="'+$scope.widget.options+'"/>');
$compile( directive)( $scope );
$element.find('.panel-body').html(directive);
```

this is not clearly the right way

Comment: what do you try to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have a controller that define a $sope.addEement method in response the controller should insert inside its html a directive passing the required directive parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the directive in your html file and use an ng-show or ng-if to determine whether the directive is shown?

```
<synergy-chart ng-show="showDirective" series="s" options="o"/>
```

If you do set the directive in the controller, use angular.element in place of '$'.

```
var directive = angular.element('<synergy-chart series="'+series+'" options="'+$scope.widget.options+'"/>');
$compile( directive)( $scope );
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
var directive = angular.element('<synergy-chart series="$scope.series" options="$scope.widget.options"/>');

$compile( directive)( $scope );
$element.find('.panel-body').html(directive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a synergyChart directive, an isolate scope, binding expressions for the configurable attributes, and a custom template.   The default behavior of the compile/link function is to insert the template as a child of the element that has the synergyChart directive.

Alternatively, instead of configurable attributes you could add a controller to the directive, and have the directive retrieve its configurable properties from the controller.  This has the advantage of allowing the configurable properties  for the directive to be set some other way (ie. service, factory, or another directive).

```
<div class="panel-body" synergy-chart="" synergy-chart-series="s" synergy-chart-options="o">
</div>

<script>
      app.directive('synergyChart', function() {
           return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: { series: '@synergy-chart-series', options: '=synergy-chart-options' },
                template: '<synergy-chart series="{{series}}" options="{{options}}"/>'
           }
      };
</script>
```